# How to generate a php page automatically directing into the root folder using a form?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, content-management-system

I want to create a form where different users are able to enter there name, and automatically a php file will be created into the root folder.

For example, 
www.domain.com/enter your name

When a user enters his/her name, a php file will generate into the root folder. The file will have his/her name on it. And every generate page will contain some codes.

Purpose of this i want to create a CMS where users can build and have their own content.

Comment: You should use a database.

Comment: Use database to generate dynamic contents

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use databases, if still you want

then u can try this, In this case if name will not be unique then content will be overridden, so validate and keep track of names;

```
$username= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$content = "<?php echo '"+$username+"';?>"; // your meassage or whatever text to save in php file.
$fp = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ."/".$username.".php","wb");
fwrite($fp,$content);
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: How would i connect to use a database to use this?

Comment: If you dont know how to connect to database using php, then thats a big problem, incase if you know then make a separate table containing all the fields you want to store in database, Make a generic template that will pull out these data based on their username and display it, you can find many tutorials on web

Comment: Oh i know how to connect, need to know how will pages auto generate into the root folder?

Comment: Pages not generate, their is one generic page which gets modified all the time when it gets data from database. Creating new pages may lead to consuming more spaces and overhead of managing pages.

Comment: Oh ok thanks for your help. I want users to have their own CMS content, but confused how the logic will work.